# How do I remove lines appearing permanently on top and bottom of a word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have these lines appearing on top and bottom of a word document (office 2010), just below and above the text (Exactly where the lines for headers and footers are). I have tried to copy the text into a new empty document, but the lines re-appear.

Comment: Check if a border has been set around the paragraph.

Comment: Are the lines actually part of the document -- do they print? They may just be Word showing you text boundaries, check your View options.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like the lines are part of the paragraph style of the text you're cutting and pasting. Open the Styles list. With your cursor in the text, open the Styles list and scroll until you see the highlighted style. Right-click on the style. Choose Modify. From the Format menu, choose Border. Click the "None" option under "Setting:" and click OK. Hopefully, that will do it.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `Endnote Separator`, `Endnote Continuation Separator` and `Endnote Continuation Notice` lines:

- Click on `View` → `Document Views` → `Draft`
- Click on `References` → `Footnotes` → `Show Notes`
- In the `Endnotes` dropdown box at the bottom of the page, select `Endnote Separator`
- Highlight the line and delete it
- Do that for each kind of Endnote
- Click on `View` → `Document Views` → `Print Layout` and the lines should be gone

Answer (score 2):

None of the above worked for me. This did: For most recent version of Word: Select "Design".In the right corner click on the "page borders" icon. Then select "none"

Answer (score 0):

Click on: Page layout / Page borders.  Then make your adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

Just right-click on the line, you'll see “edit header/footer” dialogue. Click on the dialogue and the “delete” button.